# c# get control from another void/form (eventHandler)

Tags: c#, forms, controls, eventhandler

In `form1` I created simple form called `formhaslo`.
I created in `formhaslo` control called `listBoxhaslo`
Now, I want to create `MouseDoubleClick` Event to `listBoxhaslo`.
I have problem with getting `listBoxhaslo` from `formhaslo` to `form1`.

Can you take a look at this code, please (check out comments):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form formhaslo = new Form();
...
...
...

public void buttonLoadPassForBAKFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int i = 0;
        string path = @"Backups";

        formhaslo.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

        ListBox listBoxhaslo = new ListBox();

        listBoxhaslo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 30);
        listBoxhaslo.Left = (formhaslo.ClientSize.Width - listBoxhaslo.Width) / 2;

        using (FileStream fsSbHaslo = new FileStream(path + @"\BAKPass._pass", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            using (StreamReader srhaslo = new StreamReader(fsSbHaslo, Encoding.Default))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = srhaslo.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    listBoxhaslo.Items.Add(line);
                    i++;
                }
                srhaslo.Close();
            }

                formhaslo.Controls.Add(listBoxhaslo);
                formhaslo.Controls.Add(label1);

                listBoxhaslo.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(listBoxhaslo_MouseDoubleClick); // <---here is EventHandler

                formhaslo.Show();
        }

}

void listBoxhaslo_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

        if ((listBoxhaslo.SelectedItem) != null) // <--listBoxhaslo does not exist in current context
        {
            PassForBakFile = (listBoxhaslo.SelectedItem.ToString());
            formhaslo.Hide();     
        }
}
```

I know that this error must be there because im doing it wrong but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listBoxhaslo doesn't exists because it was declare within the scope of first function which is not visible to the second function of your event listBoxhaslo_MouseDoubleClick. For you to make it work you need to declare listBoxhaslo variable outside of your function. You could declare it after formhaslo near top. Or another way to accomplish this is to cast sender to ListBox within your event.

```
void listBoxhaslo_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var listBoxhaslo = (sender as ListBox);

        if (listBoxhaslo.SelectedItem != null) 
        {
            PassForBakFile = (listBoxhaslo.SelectedItem.ToString());
            formhaslo.Hide();
        }
    }
```

I haven't tried the code but I think it will do.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks